# Drawing multiple shapes by combobox<Shape>

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am having an issue when repainting and keeping all drawn objects on the screen. Basically from my knowledge of Java (Isn't much) is that every time I repaint I am basically calling the draw method of the same object hence therefore just repainting the same object instead of a new object. On mouseRelease I am adding the shape to a list. Every element reference I assume refers to the same shape in memory and therefore calling the same draw method. How would you solve this but still keep the comboBox object oriented? I would prefer not to use strings and a switch case or else if logic.

The draw method which is same for oval and rectangle except the last line.

```
  @Override
  public void draw(Graphics context)
  {
    Point startingPoint = super.getStartingPoint();
    Point endingPoint = super.getEndingPoint();

    int minX = Math.min(endingPoint.x, startingPoint.x);
    int minY = Math.min(endingPoint.y, startingPoint.y);
    int maxX = Math.max(endingPoint.x, startingPoint.x);
    int maxY = Math.max(endingPoint.y, startingPoint.y);

    context.drawOval(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
  }
```

The JPanel which has the components and the drawing.

```
public class ShapeMakerPanel
  extends JPanel
{
  private JPanel controls;

  private JPanel currentColor;

  private JComboBox<Shape> shapeChoice;

  private JCheckBox filled;

  private JButton undo;

  private JButton clear;

  private List<Shape> list;


  public ShapeMakerPanel()
  {
    //Initialize Objects
    controls = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 10));
    currentColor = new JPanel();
    shapeChoice = new JComboBox<Shape>();
    undo = new JButton("Undo");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    filled = new JCheckBox("Filled");
    list = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    //Set object names
    controls.setName("controls");
    currentColor.setName("currentColor");
    undo.setName("undo");
    clear.setName("clear");
    shapeChoice.setName("shapeChoice");

    //Set JPanel current color to black and size it...will add jcolorchooser
    currentColor.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    currentColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));

    /*
     * Add items to comboBox, subclasses of type shape
     */
    shapeChoice.addItem(new Rectangle());
    shapeChoice.addItem(new Oval());

    //Add components to the controls panel
    controls.add(shapeChoice);
    controls.add(currentColor);
    controls.add(filled);
    controls.add(undo);
    controls.add(clear);

    //Add listeners, settings and components to main panel for frame
    addMouseListener(new ShapePanelMouseListener());
    addMouseMotionListener(new ShapePanelMouseListener());
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(controls);
  }


  public List<Shape> getShapes()
  {
    return list;
  }


  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    if (!list.isEmpty())
    {
        for (Shape s : list) {
            g2d.setColor(currentColor.getBackground());
            s.draw(g2d);
        }
    }
    g2d.dispose();
  }


  private class ShapePanelMouseListener
      extends MouseAdapter
  {

    private Shape shape;

    private ShapePanelMouseListener()
    {
        shape = (Shape)shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        shape = (Shape)shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();
        shape.setStartingPoint(e.getPoint());
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        shape = (Shape)shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();
        shape.setEndingPoint(e.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        list.add(shape);
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` with a `JComboBox`, use a `ActionListener` instead

Comment: I don't have a listener attached to the JComboBox at all. The listener is attached to the main panel.

Comment: An additional comment is that the Shape class is not of the java API but an abstract class used for learning purposes. I believe in not reinventing the wheel but it is for learning purposes only as I have never dealt with graphics before and I need to work on OOP concepts more.

Comment: In that case, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: From the looks of it, you are re-using the same instance of `Shape`, meaning that if used previously added that shape, when you try adding it again, it will simply update the properties of the existing instance, which will paint all those shapes to the same location

Comment: Sorry about that MadProgrammer, what software do you use to provide a runnable example? Also my reputation isn't really high at all and not sure if that plays a role.

Comment: Do you see any workarounds or am I better off applying a String to the comboBox and using a switch case to create a new object to the list?

Comment: See how you have some code in your question?  Create an example which is both compilable and runnable and paste that into the question instead

Comment: Thank You....I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something and that there weren't any workarounds. I will next time post a runnable example.